# How to make web design pages harmonious?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, page-layout, branding, template-design

I am working on a Pre-School Web Design, and I feel quite stuck on a point where I don't know what else I can do to make it just a little bit polished. I was using a template for base, with a lot of changes, and I feel like it doesn't have an overall harmony in terms of navigating from one page to another.

I got feedback on the same topic, "the parts I designed to the template are doesn't quite fit the overall look" and "it doesn't look harmonious".

Here are the links to the web design's pages with a little bit of description next to it, because the actual web design is in hungarian.

- [Main Page](https://ibb.co/3Rm7ZdN) / [guide](https://ibb.co/fdzL9n1) / [header appears on scroll](https://ibb.co/8sBBK5G)
- [Listing Page](https://ibb.co/59rkQtT) / [guide](https://ibb.co/kgHdyk1)
- [Profile Page](https://ibb.co/w04ng2m) / [guide](https://ibb.co/xJwZjnH)

My last two ideas were giving blue background to the listing and profile page, and to include some of the main page's decoration sitewise (like the balloons and stars on the intro) but these are not improving the overall look that much, according to my feedback source.

Any direction or idea would be helpful.

Comment: It would be helpful to future visitors if you could include screenshots rather than links (which inevitably die at some point).

Answer (score 1):

here are a couple of things that stand out to me:

I think the color scheme, especially the orange color used for some buttons and text, could use some work. There are a lot of colors going on in the pages, which makes sense to create a "playful" feel for the site, but the saturation on the orange buttons is too high compared to the rest of the illustrations.

The logo font doesn't match the font of the rest of the website - bringing these closer in style might help make the logo feel more connected to the website. In general, because of the level of detail and font, it feels like the logo is scanned in from a hand-drawing and pasted on the website.

I think the suggestions/contact section on the landing page is too wide for the amount of content it has.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Web design is much more than making a few elements look good and slapping them together on a page. Web design is about solving a problem of communication between website and audience. Concept is what you want to communicate. Conveyance is how you will communicate it. Concept: The idea behind your design.
Conveyance: The delivery of your concept. Theme: The coordination between all your design elements toward a unified whole.